# Increment operator undefined behavior in C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Say I have something like

```
int x = 5;
x = x++;
```

Is this undefined behavior in C? I have gotten a few conflicting answers on whether or not this is defined.

Comment: There is one thing undefined here and that sir is `x`. :P

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Yes, the behavior is undefined.  There is no well-defined result for the value of `x` or the behavior of the code in general.